# SQL Server 2008 : limiting subqueries by main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

First off just want to say I'm fairly a novice to SQL Server so sorry if these queries seem horribly written...

We are using SQL Server 2008.

I am running a query against our ticketing software's DB to get an idea of all the "Aging" ticket there are for each group. However it seems the numbers returned are not what is expected.

For example the below query is ran. Results are shown below

```
SELECT 
    'Group' = CASE A1.GroupName 
                 WHEN 'Internet' THEN 'Server' 
                 WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'DBA/Apps' 
                 WHEN 'Help Desk' THEN 'PIV Badge' 
                 ELSE A1.GroupName 
              END,
   ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(C2.CallID) FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C2 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A2 ON C2.CallID = A2.CallID WHERE C2.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -15, GETDATE()) AND C2.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE()) AND A2.GroupName = A1.GroupName AND C2.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C2.Category <> 'welfare' AND C2.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A2.Resolution = '' GROUP BY A2.GroupName), 0) As '15+',
   ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(C3.CallID) FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C3 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A2 ON C3.CallID = A2.CallID WHERE C3.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -31, GETDATE()) AND C3.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -60, GETDATE()) AND A2.GroupName = A1.GroupName AND C3.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C3.Category <> 'welfare' AND C3.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A2.Resolution = '' GROUP BY A2.GroupName), 0) As  '30+',
   ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(C4.CallID) FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C4 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A2 ON C4.CallID = A2.CallID WHERE C4.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -61, GETDATE()) AND C4.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -70, GETDATE()) AND A2.GroupName = A1.GroupName AND C4.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C4.Category <> 'welfare' AND C4.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A2.Resolution = '' GROUP BY A2.GroupName), 0) As  '60+',
   ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(C5.CallID) FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C5 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A2 ON C5.CallID = A2.CallID WHERE C5.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -91, GETDATE()) AND C5.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -120, GETDATE()) AND A2.GroupName = A1.GroupName AND C5.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C5.Category <> 'welfare' AND C5.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A2.Resolution = '' GROUP BY  A2.GroupName), 0) As '90+',
   ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(C6.CallID) FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C6 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A2 ON C6.CallID = A2.CallID WHERE C6.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -121, GETDATE()) AND A2.GroupName = A1.GroupName AND C6.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C6.Category <> 'welfare' AND C6.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A2.Resolution = '' GROUP BY A2.GroupName), 0) As  '120+',
   ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(C7.CallID) FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C7 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A2 ON C7.CallID = A2.CallID WHERE C7.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -15, GETDATE()) AND A2.GroupName = A1.GroupName AND C7.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C7.Category <> 'welfare' AND C7.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A2.Resolution = '' GROUP BY A2.GroupName), 0) As  'Total'
FROM 
    [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1
LEFT JOIN 
    [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID
WHERE 
    C1.CallStatus = 'Open' 
    AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' 
    AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' 
    AND A1.Resolution = '' 
    AND (A1.GroupName = 'WAN' OR 
           (A1.GroupName = 'EITS Desktop Support' 
            AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS Desktop Support' 
            AND C1.CallType <> 'Information') OR 
         A1.GroupName = 'EITS Help Desk' OR
           (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') OR
         A1.GroupName = 'Internet' OR 
         A1.GroupName = 'Telecomm' OR 
         A1.GroupName = 'Programmers' OR 
         A1.GroupName = 'Unix' OR 
         A1.GroupName = 'Web' OR 
         A1.GroupName = 'Microwave')
GROUP BY 
    A1.GroupName
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Results:

```
Group                   |15+    |30+    |60+    |90+    |120+   |Total
WAN                     |20     |17     |5      |2      |44     |100
EITS Desktop Support    |27     |15     |36     |0      |15     |96
Telecomm                |12     |15     |0      |1      |9      |50
Server                  |3      |8      |1      |0      |21     |34
Web                     |0      |6      |2      |2      |14     |30
Unix                    |1      |0      |0      |0      |27     |29
DBA/Apps                |0      |5      |3      |4      |21     |35
EITS Help Desk          |4      |2      |0      |0      |0      |6
PIV Badge               |4      |8      |1      |8      |44     |74
Microwave               |0      |3      |0      |0      |13     |16
```

When using the next query to try and see what tickets should be showing up, for EG "PIV BADGE" the tickets it show are different. This is because this query seems to be limiting the data to only to the ones for the group like it should, my question is why isn't the first query doing the same?

```
SELECT '15+' AS 'Days', C1.CallID AS 'Ticket#', A1.WhoAcknow AS 'Acknowledged By', C1.RecvdDate AS 'Received On', C1.Category, COUNT(*) As Assignments FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID WHERE C1.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -15, GETDATE()) AND C1.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE()) AND C1.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A1.Resolution = '' AND      (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') GROUP BY C1.CallID, A1.WhoAcknow, C1.RecvdDate, C1.Category UNION ALL
SELECT '30+' AS 'Days', C1.CallID AS 'Ticket#', A1.WhoAcknow AS 'Acknowledged By', C1.RecvdDate AS 'Received On', C1.Category, COUNT(*) As Assignments FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID WHERE C1.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -31, GETDATE()) AND C1.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -60, GETDATE()) AND C1.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A1.Resolution = '' AND      (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') GROUP BY C1.CallID, A1.WhoAcknow, C1.RecvdDate, C1.Category UNION ALL
SELECT '60+' AS 'Days', C1.CallID AS 'Ticket#', A1.WhoAcknow AS 'Acknowledged By', C1.RecvdDate AS 'Received On', C1.Category, COUNT(*) As Assignments FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID WHERE C1.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -61, GETDATE()) AND C1.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -70, GETDATE()) AND C1.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A1.Resolution = '' AND      (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') GROUP BY C1.CallID, A1.WhoAcknow, C1.RecvdDate, C1.Category UNION ALL
SELECT '90+' AS 'Days', C1.CallID AS 'Ticket#', A1.WhoAcknow AS 'Acknowledged By', C1.RecvdDate AS 'Received On', C1.Category, COUNT(*) As Assignments FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID WHERE C1.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -91, GETDATE()) AND C1.RecvdDate >= DATEADD(dd, -120, GETDATE()) AND C1.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A1.Resolution = '' AND     (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') GROUP BY C1.CallID, A1.WhoAcknow, C1.RecvdDate, C1.Category UNION ALL
SELECT '120+' AS 'Days', C1.CallID AS 'Ticket#', A1.WhoAcknow AS 'Acknowledged By', C1.RecvdDate AS 'Received On', C1.Category, COUNT(*) As Assignments FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1 LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID WHERE C1.RecvdDate <= DATEADD(dd, -121, GETDATE()) AND C1.CallStatus = 'Open' AND C1.Category <> 'welfare' AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS' AND A1.Resolution = '' AND                                                    (A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk' AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge') GROUP BY C1.CallID, A1.WhoAcknow, C1.RecvdDate, C1.Category ORDER BY C1.RecvdDate ASC
```

Results:

```
Days    |Ticket#    |Acknowledged By    |Received On    |Category   |Assignments
120+    |01114360   |NULL               |2014-07-16     |Helpdesk   |1
120+    |01160133   |NULL               |2014-12-01     |Helpdesk   |1
30+     |01190768   |NULL               |2015-02-24     |Helpdesk   |1
30+     |01194911   |NULL               |2015-03-06     |Helpdesk   |1
15+     |01203392   |NULL               |2015-03-26     |Helpdesk   |1
15+     |01206822   |NULL               |2015-04-03     |Helpdesk   |1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could make this a lot more efficient by using a case expression instead of a subquery for each column.

Comment: Could I get an example? I'm somewhat familiar with case expressions, however not in the way you are proposing.

Comment: Similar to what Rookie13 posted as an answer. One suggestion, I would use the datepart names instead of the shortcuts. The shortcuts are hard to remember. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: Thanks Sean for the article! I went ahead and updated my answer to reflect suggested changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your initial query, so hopefully you don't mind. But here is what I came up with:

```
WITH t
AS (
    SELECT CASE A1.GroupName
            WHEN 'Internet'
                THEN 'Server'
            WHEN 'Programmers'
                THEN 'DBA/Apps'
            WHEN 'Help Desk'
                THEN 'PIV Badge'
            ELSE A1.GroupName
            END AS [Group]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 15
                AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 30
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS '15+'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 30
                AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 60
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS '30+'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 60
                AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 90
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS '60+'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 90
                AND DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) <= 120
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS '90+'
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, C1.RecvdDate, GETDATE()) > 120
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS '120+'
    FROM [HEAT].[heat].[CallLog] C1
    LEFT JOIN [HEAT].[heat].[Asgnmnt] A1 ON C1.CallID = A1.CallID
    WHERE C1.CallStatus = 'Open'
        AND C1.Category <> 'welfare'
        AND C1.CustType <> 'IFS'
        AND A1.Resolution = ''
        AND (
            (
                A1.GroupName = 'EITS Desktop Support'
                AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS Desktop Support'
                AND C1.CallType <> 'Information'
                )
            OR (
                A1.GroupName = 'Help Desk'
                AND A1.Assignee = 'EITS PIV Badge'
                )
            OR A1.GroupName IN (
                'WAN'
                ,'EITS Help Desk'
                ,'Internet'
                ,'Telecomm'
                ,'Programmers'
                ,'Unix'
                ,'Web'
                ,'Microwave'
                )
            )
    )
SELECT t.[group]
    ,sum(t.[15+]) AS '15+'
    ,sum(t.[30+]) AS '30+'
    ,sum(t.[60+]) AS '60+'
    ,sum(t.[90+]) AS '90+'
    ,sum(t.[120+]) AS '120+'
    ,(sum(t.[15+]) + sum(t.[30+]) + sum(t.[60+]) + sum(t.[90+]) + sum(t.[120+])) AS total
FROM t
WHERE t.[Group] = 'PIV Badge'
GROUP BY t.[Group];
```